# Is rack_pjax still applicable in Rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax

I'm a newb working on my first site.    I plan on having each page load via ajax in order to have a music player run constant in the background, but I would like back-button functionality so I'm researching how to do that.

Most of the tutorials I'm finding that relate to ajax and pjax are 5-6 years old; I'm just wondering if pjax and the rack-pjax rails gem is still applicable, thanks

Comment: If you're just learning, you may get more mileage out of a more reactive solution...

Comment: I appreciate that.   I only intend to write one site  :)   You're saying it's a viable solution then

Comment: The tech will still work, if that's what you're asking. I've never tried for your use case, but it might be possible that turbolinks might be enough...

Comment: i appreciate that.     i don't think turbolinks would work in the same sense

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `pjax` to do this since `turbolinks` is already capable of this.

`Turbolinks` allows you to mark certain elements as *permanent*. Permanent elements persist across page loads, so that any changes you make to those elements do not need to be reapplied after navigation.

```
<div id="music-player" data-turbolinks-permanent>...</div>
```

> https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

**Update:**

The element that you add `data-turbolinks-permanent` attribute to, must have an unique ID, otherwise it won't work.

Designate permanent elements by giving them an HTML `id` and annotating them with `data-turbolinks-permanent`.

```
<!-- SEQUENCER MODAL BODY -->
<div class="modal-body" id="music_player_modal" data-turbolinks-permanent>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 nav-index" id="sequencerIndex">
        <div id="jp_container_1">
          <div class="jp-playlist">
            <ul>
              <li></li> <!-- Empty <li> so your HTML conforms with the W3C spec -->
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Before each render, Turbolinks matches all permanent elements by `id` and transfers them from the original page to the new page, preserving their data and event listeners.

Comment: hey man, i appreciate that.   that'd be a great solution if i could make it work.  not sure where to put it, as the jPlayer code is spread all over, and only in modals opened from the navbar.   i've updated the question

Comment: i think the problem is is that the music player is run from javascript in a modal.. how do i turbolink permanent that?

Comment: i blasted in pjax and have since moved on, but i wish i would have seen your update last night to try it.    still, i found several forum posts where people posted similar questions with turbolinks as a possible answer, including one which included a response from turbolinks in which they said it wasn't designed for it, and to go with pjax.   so that's what i did